# What is the most complete study of Count Benyowszky?

Tags: poland, resource, hungary, kamchatka, madagascar

[Maurice Benyowsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Benyovszky) was a notorious adventurer who wrote a well-known, highly fictionalized autobiography (*Memoirs and Travels of Mauritius Augustus Count de Benyowsky*). His supposed exploits became famous enough to be the basis of plays and operas.

This is a source request: has any modern scholar sought to sort the fact from the fiction? I did find a breezy 1989 biographical sketch in French, *Héros ou imposteur? Un aventurier au XVIIIe siècle* by Miklós Molnár, but there seems to be much more to the story. The best work on him might have been done in the Hungarian or Polish languages; [several relevant books](http://www.benyovszky.hu/eletrajz/) were written in the late 1800s. The multiple spellings of his surname make searching for him rather a challenge.